# What is the best way to make an if statement condition itself conditional?

Tags: readability, logical-operator

Apologies if this is answered elsewhere here but this specific question is somewhat hard to search for as you might see. I'm writing a script currently that essentially has a simple if-then within a for-loop like so:

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
         if (a < b)
              { ... }
    }
```

However I want to reverse the if statement based on another condition, in my case user input, which the most obvious solution for my novice brain would be to have two if-then's inside a 3rd if-then:

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (input)
            {
                if (a < b)
                    { ... }  // exactly the same code as in the for loop
            } else {
                if (a > b)
                    { ... } // exactly the same code as above
            }
    }
```

But having two sets of if-thens that are nearly identical except for the condition direction feels wrong. I know I could swap a and b values using an array or something but would wind up with nearly as many lines of code anyways. Surely there is a more clever and simple way to do this?

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) what goes inside the `{ ... }` elided part. For example, are both of those the same? In which case we could simply test `if (a != b)`, modulo `NaN` detection. Are they related bits of code which could be broken out as a helper function and invoked as either `helper(a, b)` or `helper(b, a)` ? Help us to help you. Some more motivation of the use case is needed, since the identifiers `a` and `b` don't really shed any light upon it. Also, should we be testing `input` before even launching a `for` loop? Or make it a 3rd arg?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly reverse the if statement when you have two conditions in it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306881/how-to-properly-reverse-the-if-statement-when-you-have-two-conditions-in-it)

Comment: Thanks @J_H yes the elisions are the same code. A fully reproducible example wont fit in a comment but I can explain a bit more what it's actually for: In short it's a pixel shader that's evaluating a pixel `a` compared to a neighbor `b`, and be able to reverse the evaluation based on a user input flag/bool. I thought about something like `helper(a, b)` but feels like overkill and more code than it is currently. Your `if ( a != b)`, modulo `NaN` *sounds* like what I was looking for as a solution but would need you to expand on how that would actually work!

Comment: @Rushkie: clarifying information belongs into the question, that's what the "edit" button above is for. Here down in the comments such information gets lost.

Comment: A possible bug... what if a == b ?

Comment: @Rushkie: is it really so much effort to use the "edit" button to make this a proper question? Let me do this for you, please double check if I got your comment right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator: `if (input ? a < b : a > b) { ... }`.

However, without properly naming the conditions or adding a comment your code will be harder to read, as it might not be obvious why the condition is different depending on `input`.

Comment: Thanks I've never used a ternary with sub-logic before that makes sense and is a good solution for this!

Answer (score 10):

add more functions:

```
buttonPress()
{
    if(input)
    {
       process(a, b)
    }
    else
    {
       process(b, a)
    }
}

process(a, b)
{
    for(i=0 ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well... I think that a good way to do that is to encapsulate your code into procedures/functions and correctly naming your steps/conditionals, like this:

```
function iterateOverSomething() {
  for (...) {
    handleIteration(input, a, b);
  }
}

function handleIteration(input, a, b) {
  const isInputNotEmpty = input.length != 0;
  const isALessThanB = a < b;
  const isAGreaterThanB = a > b;

  if (isInputNotEmpty) {
    return isALessThanB && doSomething();
  }

  return isAGreaterThanB && doSomethingElse();
}

function doSomething() {
  // ...
}

function doSomethingElse() {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always reduce cyclomatic complexity this way:

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        flag = input;   
        if ((flag && (a < b)) || (!flag && (a > b))) {
            ...
        }   
}
```

If input was a costly function instead of a variable, like `input()`, assigning it to flag prevents calling it twice, otherwise it's not necessary to use the flag.

Comment: That would duplicate the code in `{ ... }` which the OP wishes to avoid.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner Oh, it wasn't clear to me that was the intent, but I edited it and I believe it achieves the goal now.

Answer (score 1):

In a language where you have lambdas you can easily return predicates (functions return booleans) to eliminate nested `if`.

```
predicate = if (input) {
  (a, b) => a < b
} else {
  (a, b) => a > b
}
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (predicate(a, b)) {
    }
}
```